# How many positive integers are there such that when $n$ is divided by $11$, the quotient equals the remainder?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

How many positive integers are there such that when $n$ is divided by $11$, the quotient equals the remainder ?

My try follows:

$12 \equiv 1 \pmod{11}$, and $Q = 1$

$24 \equiv 2 \pmod{11}$, and $Q = 2$

$36 \equiv 3 \pmod{11}$, and $Q = 3$

It seems that only multiples of $12$ work.

Is there any way to prove this conclusion?

Thank you for your help.
EDITE : since  the number of positive  remainders upon division  of  $11$  is $10$ 
The answer is $10$ values

Comment: We need $11r+r=r(11+1)$

Comment: @ lab bhattacharjee Thank you very much , got it

Comment: @N. F. Taussig thank  you for making my question much clearer

Comment: You're welcome.  Here is a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: You're going to have to do some workarounds for $Q > 10$.